# JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN as header

Tags: authentication, frontend, token, github-api, jspm

I am having trouble with a github alert that is telling me the following:

"*On September 11th, 2020 at 18:16 (UTC) your personal access token (JSPM_PRUEBA) using jspm was used as part of a query parameter to access an endpoint through the GitHub API:
Please use the Authorization HTTP header instead, as using the `access_token` query parameter is deprecated. If this token is being used by an app you don't have control over, be aware that it may stop working as a result of this deprecation.*"

The alert it is being triggered when I am doing a jspm install through a docker image that generates the dist folder with an npm install and then a jspm install inside it. The docker is being provided with a parameter JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN with a github PAT that is being generate and later obtained using:

jspm registry config github
jspm registry export github

I believe this is working fine because the alert is showing the right PAT name "JSPM_PRUEBA".

The actual question is, what is what I need to configure to include the access_token as a header and not as a query param while pulling the jspm dependencies.

Need some help please.

package.son

```
    {
      "name": "aleph-media-ui",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "aleph-media-ui",
      "main": "app/app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "sh configure.sh"
      },
      "moduleConfig": {
        "mainJs": "app/app.js",
        "source": "app/**/*.js",
        "templates": "app/**/*.html",
        "sass": [
          "styles/**/*.scss",
          "styles/**/*.css"
        ],
        "output": "dist/",
        "build": "build/",
        "port": "18093"
      },
      "jspm": {
        "registry": "jspm",
        "directories": {
          "lib": "build"
        },
        "dependencies": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
          "angular-bootstrap": "bower:angular-bootstrap@0.13.4",
          "angular-encode-uri": "bower:angular-encode-uri@^1.0.0",
          "angular-environment": "npm:angular-environment@^1.0.8",
          "angular-material": "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.1",
          "angular-messages": "npm:angular-messages@^1.4.9",
          "angular-resource": "github:angular/bower-angular-resource@1.4.5",
          "angular-route": "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.5",
          "angular-ui-mask": "bower:angular-ui-mask@^1.8.3",
          "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15",
          "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@3.4.1",
          "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15",
          "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
          "module-crud-ui": "npm-redbee:module-crud-ui@1.2.5-beta",
          "module-layout-ui": "npm-redbee:module-layout-ui@1.3.9-SNAPSHOT",
          "module-security-ui": "npm-redbee:module-security-ui@1.0.3-SNAPSHOT",
          "remarkable-bootstrap-notify": "bower:remarkable-bootstrap-notify@^3.1.3"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
          "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
          "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
        }
      },
      "publishConfig": {
        "registry": "https://nexus.uat.aleph.turner.com/repository/npm-redbee"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
        "browser-sync": "^2.9.3",
        "del": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp": "^3.9.0",
        "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^5.2.1",
        "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-cdnify": "^1.0.3-pre",
        "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
        "gulp-css-base64": "^1.3.2",
        "gulp-img64": "0.0.6",
        "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
        "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.4",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
        "gulp-replace-task": "^0.11.0",
        "gulp-run": "^1.6.10",
        "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
        "gulp-sonar": "^1.0.3",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
        "gulp-strip-code": "^0.1.2",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.1",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
        "isparta": "^3.0.3",
        "istanbul": "^0.3.18",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
        "jspm": "^0.16.1",
        "jspm-bower-endpoint": "^0.3.2",
        "karma": "^0.13.9",
        "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^5.2.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "^0.5.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
        "karma-jspm": "^2.0.1",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.4",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
        "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
        "proxy-middleware": "^0.14.0",
        "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
        "run-sequence": "^1.1.2",
        "url": "^0.11.0",
        "vinyl-paths": "^1.0.0",
        "angular-environment": "^1.0.8"
      }
    }
```

config.js

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "app/*": "dist/app/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "npm-redbee:*": "jspm_packages/npm-redbee/*",
    "bower:*": "jspm_packages/bower/*"
  },

  map: {
    "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "bower:angular-bootstrap@0.13.4",
    "angular-encode-uri": "bower:angular-encode-uri@1.0.0",
    "angular-environment": "npm:angular-environment@1.0.8",
    "angular-material": "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.1",
    "angular-messages": "npm:angular-messages@1.4.9",
    "angular-resource": "github:angular/bower-angular-resource@1.4.5",
    "angular-route": "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.5",
    "angular-ui-mask": "bower:angular-ui-mask@1.8.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.35",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.35",
    "bootstrap-sweetalert": "bower:bootstrap-sweetalert@0.4.5",
    "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@3.4.1",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15",
    "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
    "module-crud-ui": "npm-redbee:module-crud-ui@1.2.5-beta",
    "module-layout-ui": "npm-redbee:module-layout-ui@1.3.9-SNAPSHOT",
    "module-security-ui": "npm-redbee:module-security-ui@1.0.3-SNAPSHOT",
    "remarkable-bootstrap-notify": "bower:remarkable-bootstrap-notify@3.1.3",
    "bower:angular-bootstrap@0.13.4": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "bower:angular-bootstrap@1.3.3": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.5.5"
    },
    "bower:angular-cookies@1.4.5": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "bower:angular-encode-uri@1.0.0": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "bower:angular-growl-v2@0.7.9": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.4.5",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "bower:angular-ui-mask@1.8.3": {
      "angular": "bower:angular@1.5.5"
    },
    "bower:bootstrap-sweetalert@0.4.5": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "bower:bootstrap@3.3.6": {
      "jquery": "bower:jquery@2.2.1"
    },
    "bower:material-design-iconic-font@2.1.2": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "bower:remarkable-bootstrap-notify@3.1.3": {
      "bootstrap": "bower:bootstrap@3.3.6",
      "jquery": "bower:jquery@2.2.1"
    },
    "github:angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files@2.10.0": {
      "angular-translate": "github:angular-translate/bower-angular-translate@2.10.0"
    },
    "github:angular-translate/bower-angular-translate@2.10.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.8": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.8": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-cookies@1.5.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-mocks@1.4.4": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.4": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.5": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-sanitize@1.5.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
      "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.8",
      "angular-aria": "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.8",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.1": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
      "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.8",
      "angular-aria": "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.8",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@0.8.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
      "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1": {
      "Base64": "npm:Base64@0.2.1",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0": {
      "https-browserify": "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0": {
      "os-browserify": "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0": {
      "url": "npm:url@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm-redbee:module-crud-ui@1.2.5-beta": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
      "angular-mocks": "github:angular/bower-angular-mocks@1.4.4",
      "angular-resource": "github:angular/bower-angular-resource@1.4.4",
      "angular-route": "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.4",
      "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15"
    },
    "npm-redbee:module-layout-ui@1.3.9-SNAPSHOT": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.5",
      "angular-bootstrap": "bower:angular-bootstrap@1.3.3",
      "angular-cookies": "github:angular/bower-angular-cookies@1.5.0",
      "angular-growl-v2": "bower:angular-growl-v2@0.7.9",
      "angular-loading-bar": "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@0.8.0",
      "angular-material": "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.0",
      "angular-sanitize": "github:angular/bower-angular-sanitize@1.5.0",
      "angular-translate": "github:angular-translate/bower-angular-translate@2.10.0",
      "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "github:angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files@2.10.0",
      "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15",
      "angular-utils-ui-breadcrumbs": "bower:angular-utils-ui-breadcrumbs@0.2.2",
      "bootstrap-sweetalert": "bower:bootstrap-sweetalert@0.4.5",
      "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@3.4.1",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.15",
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
      "material-design-iconic-font": "bower:material-design-iconic-font@2.1.2"
    },
    "npm-redbee:module-security-ui@1.0.3-SNAPSHOT": {
      "angular-cookies": "bower:angular-cookies@1.4.5",
      "angular-uuid": "npm:angular-uuid@0.0.2"
    },
    "npm:amdefine@1.0.0": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "module": "github:jspm/nodelibs-module@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:angular-uuid@0.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.35": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:clean-css@3.4.1": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "commander": "npm:commander@2.8.1",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1",
      "https": "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0",
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "source-map": "npm:source-map@0.4.4",
      "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:commander@2.8.1": {
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "graceful-readlink": "npm:graceful-readlink@1.0.1",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.6": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:graceful-readlink@1.0.1": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2": {
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:punycode@1.3.2": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "npm:source-map@0.4.4": {
      "amdefine": "npm:amdefine@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13"
    },
    "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:url@0.10.3": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "punycode": "npm:punycode@1.3.2",
      "querystring": "npm:querystring@0.2.0",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your are using an older version of the jspm github package. From the source code, it seems that it used the `access_token` query parameter in version < 1.0.0.

For instance, 0.13.20 version [used the access_token query parameter](https://github.com/jspm/github/blob/8d701b62e1dc67b9d2e85bf9873bef5384cdf37a/github.js#L40) contrary the newest package version (any version after 1.0.0)

It also seems that the package name has changed from [jspm-github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspm-github) to [@jspm/github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jspm/github) for version >= 1.0.0. So you may just need to use the new [@jspm/github package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jspm/github) instead

Comment: Hi Bertrand, thank you for the answer. Just to be honest, I am no front-end expert. I kind of understand that I need to upgrade but I have no clew where I must change what you are telling me. I have attached the package.json and config.js which I believe are the dependency for npm and jspm respectively.  If I change jspm version to 1.0.0 I get npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: jspm@^1.0.0.   Just one more thing to mention I am using NVM for hosting multipe npm versions. Using V6.9.0

Comment: @LucasFavaro I think you need to upgrade your jspm cli tool to version 2.0.0-beta.7 : https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.7 . It's the cli tool that seems to use jspm-github under the hood: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/package.json#L9

Comment: so Bertrand how would that be traduced inside the dependency specs that I have because when I upgrade to 2.0.0-beta.7 it crashes with another error. Also I don't know where to configure the @jspm/github